# Deleting temp directory from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a smart way of deleting old files from the hdfs /tmp directory? (Just to make sure, I am not talking about the unix FS /tmp)

Comment: Define "smart".

Comment: I can parse the output of -lsr but I dont consider it too smart. Also, I cant list anything by date :(

Answer (score 2):

`hadoop fs -stat "%Y" "/path/*"` Will output timestamps of everything in /path/. Use that along with a cut off as to what you consider too young and you can have this clean up in a shell script kicked off by cron.

This might be smarter then parsing other things outputted by hadoop fs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's (the source code of) a small tool that does the job: https://github.com/mag-/hdfs-cleanup/

I might write one on my own (or port the given one to Python) so I don't need to create a build chain for Golang in my company.

And one more for Ruby users: https://github.com/nmilford/clean-hadoop-tmp